# Cannot match any routes when using :id

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, router

I'm trying to use an Angular router to go through the link with an id. I added in routing-module a link with an id, but it doesn't work.

I have tried to ways of using routes. Like: `{ path: 'user/:id', component: UserPage}` and `{ path: '/user/:id', component: UserPage}`
But none of them works.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'user/:id', component: UserPage}
];
```

---

```
userClick(id: number) {
    this._router.navigate([`/user`, id]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the link completely ([Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)) unless it was a direct route from the root.

Example: You have `randomlink` and you want to access `/user` you can use as you currently used. But if you want to access `randomlink/someroute/user` you need to specify `someroute/user`

See the following example: [Stackblitz Routing Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-navigation?file=app%2Fpeople%2Fpeople-routing.module.ts)